# React Native, how to make countdown run in background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I build screen for otp verification, I added countdown when countdown is over user can request for otp again, but I'm facing a problem that when user minimize the app countdown is not working. Below is code

```
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(30);
....
useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (timer > 0) setTimer(timer - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
    };
  }, [timer]);
...
const resendOtp = () => {
    actions
      .resendOtp()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, 'the resuel');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    setTimer(30);
    setModalVisible(false);
  };
....
```

can someone please tell me what's wrong?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you could do that with vanilla. For me, I use  'react-native-background-timer' library. It seems to work.

Repo - https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer